# Optimated back-button to camera-activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera

in my android project i scan a image and then gets redirected to a new activity. In onPause i release my camera and in onResume i re-create it.

When using my back-button to go back to the camera-view; i get the feeling that it reacts slowly. I know for a fact that this i because the program dont change view before i created new camera instance in onResume.

My question is: How can i make the program show camera-activity view before making the camera instance to make everything "look" faster?

Hope i am clear! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer to Android [Camera online document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29):

> Caution: On some devices, this method may take a long time to
>   complete. It is best to call this method from a worker thread
>   (possibly using AsyncTask) to avoid blocking the main application UI
>   thread.

Comment: Seems that there are no other sane way. Thanks!

I am going to try refactor my program to use fragments instead, that way i wont need to release the camera every time when changing activity(fragments).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can open() camera in a background thread. I am not sure that this is what slows your activity display.

Comment: Yes, it is the camera.open() that slows my display as i wasn't doing it asynchronously.